# jQuery ajaxPrefilter and Expression Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a jQuery ajaxPrefilter to work with the following JS code. Here is the code I use to call the ajax function.

```
var $setallow = $(".show");
$setallow.click(function() {
    var $allow = $(this).closest("form");
    var formData = $allow.serialize();
    submitForm(formData);
});
function submitForm(formData) {

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/schedule_update.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 8000,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            },
        error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
    });
};
```

Here is the prefilter code I want to use.  This code was provided by [Expression Engine](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/security.html#ajax).

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
     var old_xid = EE.XID;

     jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-EEXID", old_xid);

     jqXHR.complete(function(xhr) {
        var new_xid = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-EEXID');

        if (new_xid) {
           EE.XID = new_xid;
           $('input[name="XID"]').filter('[value="'+old_xid+'"]').val(new_xid);
        }
     });
});
```

Here is the HTML code with the form.

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="allow" value="yes" class="show" />
</form>
```

How can I make this prefilter work with my code?  As soon as I add the prefilter to any part of my JS code, the form is no longer submitted to my php page to update the DB.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also came into this problem and couldn't figure it out. If the plan is to create a new XID code, why not return it by the ajax call from the php script. Just add the "XID_SECURE_HASH" within the json_encode function like so:

```
<?php
    public function get_new_xid_hash() {
        $data = array('XID' => XID_SECURE_HASH, 'otherData' => 'Show this text');

        echo json_encode($data);
        die();
    }
?>
```

The return from the ajax call can be like so:

```
success: function(data) {
    EE.XID = data.XID;
}
```

So the next time you're ajax makes a request, it will include the updated XID code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using your php code to return the XID_SECURE_HASH to the html page with the JS.  I also used the EE.XID in the success of the AJAX call along with using the ajaxPrefilter provided by expression engine.  The page still won't submit.  I think there is an error with the AJAX prefilter.  Did you use the exact same prefilter code?  I tried putting the prefilter code in the submitform function to no avail.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I gave up on the AJAX prefilter as it didn't work for me either. For the form you can add to the hidden input field something like "$('input[name="XID"]').val(EE.XID)" within the "submitForm" function before the AJAX call. Or you can call the XID_SECURE_HASH within the form field itself like "<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="<?php echo XID_SECURE_HASH; ?>" />".